# How to avoid last comma when adding json with fs.createWriteStream in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, json, fs, createwritestream

I'm using [fs.createWriteStream()](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options) to add JSON-data asynchronously to a file with file.write(JSON.stringify(data) + ","). So every json-object is followed by a comma. How can I avoid/remove the comma after the last json-object inside the code?

```
{"key1":"value1"}, {"key2":"value2"},
```

Comment: If it's really `JSON` then `object`s will already be delimited by commas. `JSON.stringify(data) + ","` adds a comma to the end of your stringified `data`.

Comment: You need to add a condition on the last json-object check is it last or not, if it is last then don't place the comma in the end.

Comment: Is your JSON data really more than 1GB? Or are you running your software on a really small machine with only 500MB RAM?